# Mongo Dump and Restore of databases

Tags: database, mongodb, bash, mongodump, mongorestore

I have a mongo database where I took a dump of that database from source environment and restoring the database in target environment but the size is changing from dump to restore. So, I was checking for ways to compare db.stats() for that DB before dumping and restoring on both environments. If there is mismatch with db size throw an exception or message stating its diff size using a bash script

Can someone let me know ways to check this approach

Comment: To be more specific How can I compare two mongo databases using a shell script. Not a javascript and already went over mongo collected exampls